# Why doesn't this PHP SimpleXML XPath find the values?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm expecting an array of `Amount`, but for some reason it refused to be found. I tried many combinations of setting the name space, but it gives the error `SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): Undefined namespace prefix`.

`Code`

```
      // $xml->registerXPathNamespace("amazon", "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01");
      // $item->registerXPathNamespace("amazon", "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01");
      // $possiblePrices = $item->OfferSummary->xpath('//amazon:Amount');
      $possiblePrices = $item->OfferSummary->xpath('//Amount');
      Yii::error(print_r($item->OfferSummary->asXML(), true));
      Yii::error(print_r($possiblePrices, true));
```

`Log`

```
2015-04-15 21:46:06 [::1][-][-][error][application] <OfferSummary><LowestNewPrice><Amount>1</Amount><CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode><FormattedPrice>$0.01</FormattedPrice></LowestNewPrice><TotalNew>15</TotalNew><TotalUsed>0</TotalUsed><TotalCollectible>0</TotalCollectible><TotalRefurbished>0</TotalRefurbished></OfferSummary>
    in /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/xxx/controllers/ShoppingController.php:208
    in /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/xxx/controllers/ShoppingController.php:106
2015-04-15 21:46:06 [::1][-][-][error][application] Array
(
)
```

`Top of XML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ItemSearchResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
```

Comment: Can you post a more complete sample of the original XML, prior to calling `asXML()`

Comment: Here is the complete XML http://pastebin.com/U5ar3UQh

Comment: This seems to address the default namespace (without element prefixes) issue you're dealing with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143846/xpath-in-simplexml-for-default-namespaces-without-needing-prefixes

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Well I did try to use namespaces. See line 1,2,3 of the code. However they give an error.

Comment: I missed/ignored commented out code. What error did it result in? That isn't in your post.

Comment: Yes, it's in the post. The error is `SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): Undefined namespace prefix`.

Comment: Not familiar with PHP, but since you registered the namespace to `$item`, maybe this way will do : `$item->xpath('//amazon:OfferSummary//amazon:Amount');` ?

Comment: @har07 Wow. That was it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *`Amount`* element is in the namespace `<http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01>`. But in your xpath query you put it in no namespace at all. So the example will return 0 elements:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);

$result = $xml->xpath('//Amount');
printf("Result (%d):\n", count($result));
foreach ($result as $node) {
    echo $node->asXML(), "\n";
}
```

The output is rather short:

```
Result (0):
```

Instead you need to tell that you want the *`Amount`* element in that specific namespace. You do that by registering a namespace-prefix and use it in your xpath query:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("amazon", "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01");
$result = $xml->xpath('//amazon:Amount');
printf("Result (%d):\n", count($result));
foreach ($result as $node) {
    echo $node->asXML(), "\n";
}
```

Now the output is with all those elements:

```
Result (24):
<Amount>217</Amount>
<Amount>1</Amount>
<Amount>800</Amount>
<Amount>1</Amount>
<Amount>498</Amount>
...
```

Take care that if you've got more than one element-name to check for in your xpath query, that you need to tell the correct namespace for each of them. Example:

```
$result = $xml->xpath('/*/amazon:Items/amazon:Item//amazon:Amount');
```

You can find the example code also online here: https://eval.in/314347 ([backup](https://gist.github.com/hakre/66290593a94e2327ead8))- otherwise the examples from my answer minus the XML at a glance:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);

$result = $xml->xpath('//Amount');
printf("Result (%d):\n", count($result));
foreach ($result as $node) {
    echo $node->asXML(), "\n";
}

$xml->registerXPathNamespace("amazon", "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01");
$result = $xml->xpath('//amazon:Amount');
printf("Result (%d):\n", count($result));
foreach ($result as $node) {
    echo $node->asXML(), "\n";
}

$result = $xml->xpath('/*/amazon:Items/amazon:Item//amazon:Amount');
printf("Result (%d):\n", count($result));
foreach ($result as $node) {
    echo $node->asXML(), "\n";
}
```

### Further Readings

- [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/595946/367456)
- [XPath in SimpleXML for default namespaces without needing prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21143846/367456)

---

If you don't want to register the namespace prefixes over and over again, you can extend from **SimpleXMLElement** and manage that registration list your own:

```
/**
 * Class MyXml
 *
 * Example on how to register xpath namespace prefixes within the document
 */
class MyXml extends SimpleXMLElement
{
    public function registerXPathNamespace($prefix, $ns)
    {
        $doc        = dom_import_simplexml($this)->ownerDocument;
        $doc->__sr  = $doc;
        $doc->__d[] = [$prefix, $ns];
    }

    public function xpath($path)
    {
        $doc = dom_import_simplexml($this)->ownerDocument;
        if (isset($doc->__d)) {
            foreach ($doc->__d as $v) {
                parent::registerXPathNamespace($v[0], $v[1]);
            }
        }

        return parent::xpath($path);
    }
}
```

With this **MyXml** class you can load the document and then you would only need to register the namespace once:

```
$namespace = "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01";

$xml = simplexml_load_file('so-29664051.xml', 'MyXMl');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("amazon", $namespace);

$item = $xml->Items->Item[0];

$result = $item->xpath('.//amazon:Amount');
printf("Result (%d):\n", count($result));
foreach ($result as $node) {
    echo $node->asXML(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: That wasn't really the problem. I tried using namespaces. See line 1,2,3 of the code. The problem was pointed out by @har07. I thought setting the namespace on an element would propagate/inherit to the children, but it doesn't, so I have to set the namespace on the exact child object that I use `xpath()` with.

Comment: Ah! Yes you have to or you let SimpleXML do that for you by extending from it. I'll add an example on how you can to that.