# xpath exploding integers and comparing values

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I need to create an xpath query that looks for books that have a feedback rating of 98%+ but Amazon returns an estimated feedback so instead of returning the string `'98'` it returns `'98-100%'`

is there an easy way to extract the first number from `'98-100%'` string so that I can run comparisons using xpath?

Below is the current query I am using.

```
foreach($xml->xpath("//c:LowestOfferListing[./c:Qualifiers/c:SellerPositiveFeedbackRating = '98-100%']") as $listing) print_r($listing)
```

Ideally I want something such as:

```
foreach($xml->xpath("//c:LowestOfferListing[./c:Qualifiers/c:SellerPositiveFeedbackRating > 98]") as $listing) print_r($listing);
```

Comment: A related chunk of XML can be found in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29877169/367456).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that feedback rating always in the form of range containing `-` as separator, you can try this xpath (formatted for readability) :

```
//c:LowestOfferListing[
        ./c:Qualifiers
         /c:SellerPositiveFeedbackRating[
                substring-before(., '-') >= 98
        ]
]
```

For reference :

- [MDN: xpath `substring-before()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-before)