# Hive XPath UDF alongside namespaces doesn't work

Tags: xml, hadoop, xpath, hive, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to use a UDF to parse my xml document. If I run the following, it works:

```
select xpath_string('<Application><applicationId>test</applicationId></Application>', '//applicationId') as id 
from my_table limit 2;
```

output is:

```
OK
test
test
```

If now I run the following code but add a namespace, I won't be able to parse my XML:

```
select xpath_string('<Application xmlns="http://domain.com/test"><applicationId>test</applicationId></Application>', '//applicationId') as id 
from my_table limit 2;
```

I will only get empty strings.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong? Or should I improve my XPath?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2nd XML introduces *default namespace*, which affect not only the element where default namespace is declared but also all descendant elements without prefix, including `applicationId` element :

```
xmlns="http://domain.com/test"
```

Commonly, you need to map a prefix, say `d`, to the default namespace uri and use that prefix in the XPath : `//d:applicationId`. I'm not familiar with the technology that you use, so not sure how and whether this approach is supported.

The following is a pure XPath 1.0 alternative :

```
//*[local-name()='applicationId' and namespace-uri()='http://domain.com/test']
```

or ignoring the namespace if you like :

```
//*[local-name()='applicationId']
```

Comment: out of curiosity, why for other namespaces when not default, I could do d:applicationId, but the parser isn't smart enough when the namespace isn't specified, to just imply the default one?

Comment: See the explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21149866/2998271). That thread is about simplexml, which behave the same as you explained: it implies namespaces only for non-default namespace

Comment: insightful thanks. Best would be to recommend the people providing my xml to explicitely add a letter for the namespace. That would heavily simplify my xpath queries