# How to get array element in SimpleXMLElement in php?

Tags: php, simplexml

I do have the following SimpleXMLElement:

```
SimpleXMLElement {#812 ▼
  +"title": "Telas x Metro"
  +"link": SimpleXMLElement {#876 ▶}
  +"updated": "2020-09-16T15:36:53Z"
  +"author": SimpleXMLElement {#883 ▶}
  +"id": "/googleshopping.xml"
  +"entry": array:4 [▼
    0 => SimpleXMLElement {#881 ▶}
    1 => SimpleXMLElement {#895 ▶}
    2 => SimpleXMLElement {#893 ▶}
    3 => SimpleXMLElement {#873 ▶}
  ]
}
```

And I would like to access to the entry element and the do a foreach on it. but when I do this:

`var_dump($xml->entry)`

I only get first element

and if i do this:

`var_dump($xml->xpath('//entry'))`

I get a empty array.

this is the xml file: http://www.telasxmetro.com/XMLData/googleshopping.xml

This is my code:

```
xml = simplexml_load_file(
 's3://'.env('AWS_BUCKET').'/'.$path,//this is the same xml.
 'SimpleXMLElement',
 LIBXML_NOCDATA
);

foreach ($xml->xpath('//entry') as $item) {
//empty array, so dont enter the loop.
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: I just added some code, my only problem is to get the full array, then using a foreach on it.

Comment: so try `foreach ($xml->entry as $item) { var_dump($item); }`

Comment: As you have a default namespace (`xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"`) you will have to register it and use that as part of your XPath, sort of dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143846/xpath-in-simplexml-for-default-namespaces-without-needing-prefixes or something similar.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried and I only get the first element of the array.

Comment: Yes, first time round the loop you get Occurance1 and then Occ2 etc etc

Comment: @RiggsFolly i know, but I did var_dump($xml->entry) just before the loop and I got only the first element.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a self-contained XML sample, and the actual code you're having problems with, along with the exact output you're getting and the exact output your expecting (in other words, a [mcve]).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.telasxmetro.com/XMLData/googleshopping.xml');

echo count($xml->entry) . ' Occurances' . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($xml->entry as $item) {
    echo $item->title . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output is

```
818 Occurances

Lona estampada Hojas Tropicales Verde y Rosa
Lienzo Rayado Rojo
Lienzo Rayado Negro
Lienzo Rayado Azul
Lienzo Crudo 1,60 mt. de ancho.
Lona estampada Flores Turquesa Fondo Blanco
Lona estampada Flores Negras Fondo Blanco

etc etc
```